# how to break long text to smaller lines by words in ruby/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to break long text to smaller lines by words?
Ideally, I need method like

```
def text_splitter(text, line_size = 5)
    # ...
end

text_splitter("a b c d e text longword") # => ["a b c", "d e ", "text ", "longword"]
```

Comment: can you have an entry text without spaces?

Comment: also can a word from the text be splitted? (longword => long word)

Comment: I think no, If method meets longword it should skip it as is, in order to be able to handle it manually, for example add ellipsis or split by characters.

Comment: The [`word_wrap`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-word_wrap) helper can split long lines using a delimiter. If you need an array, you could adapt its source code. (it's basically a regex)

Comment: @Stefan, it is exactly what I find, thanks! I will accept answer if you post it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails comes with the [`word_wrap`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-word_wrap) helper which can split long lines based on a given line width. It always splits at whitespace so long words won't get split / cut.

In `rails/console`:

```
lines = helper.word_wrap("a b c d e text longword", line_width: 5)
#=> "a b c\nd e\ntext\nlongword"

puts lines
```

Output:

```
a b c
d e
text
longword
```

Note that it returns a string, not an array.

Answer (score 3):

That can be done in pure-Ruby as follows<sup>1</sup>.

```
def text_splitter(text, line_size)
  text.gsub(/(?:.{1,#{line_size}}|\S+)\K(?:$|\s)/, "\n")
end
```

```
text = "Beware the Jabberwock, my son! The jaws that bite, the claws that catch!"
```

```
puts text_splitter(text, 30)
0        1         2         3
123456789012345678901234567890
Beware the Jabberwock, my son!
The jaws that bite, the claws
that catch!
```

```
puts text_splitter(text, 20)
0        1         2
12345678901234567890
Beware the
Jabberwock, my son!
The jaws that bite,
the claws that
catch!
```

```
puts text_splitter(text, 10)
0        1
1234567890
Beware the
Jabberwock,
my son!
The jaws
that bite,
the claws
that
catch!
```

```
puts text_splitter(text, 8)
0
12345678
Beware
the
Jabberwock,
my son!
The jaws
that
bite,
the
claws
that
catch!
```

---

The regular expression can be broken down as follows (for `line_size = 10`):

```
(?:         # begin non-capture group
  .{1,10}   # match 1-10 chars
  |         # or 
  \S+       # match >= 1 non-whitespace chars
)           # end non-capture group
\K          # reset start of match and discard all chars previously matched
(?:$|\s)    # match the end of the string or a whitespace chars
```

<sup>1. Sample text is from Lewis Carrol's peom, "Jabberwocky".</sup>